# When did a nation-state first give at least lip service to the belief that subjugating another nation by force was morally or otherwise unacceptable?

Tags: imperialism

When did a nation-state first give at least lip service to the belief that subjugating another nation by force was morally or otherwise unacceptable? My impression is that it was universally accepted as proper for to increase is territory, wealth, power and prestige. Indeed, the Roman Empire seems to have existed solely by and for the subjection of other nations.

Comment: If you mean when did governments officially say that wars of conquest are inherently wrong, not until the United Nations charter.

Comment: Thank you for your question; could you give us an overview of the [research you have done so far](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599) and explain what you find to be unclear or missing? Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) may be helpful.

Comment: The invaded party asserted this the first time a nation-state was invaded. Note that by using the term nation-state, you're bounding this to post-15th century.....

Comment: Modern European democratic nation states date back to the French Revolution, itself inspired by the American one, both fruits of the Enlightenment.

Comment: Since states were born in Ancient times, let me consider this: Ancient Egypt, quite a strong state, did not try to conquer its surrounding territories, for most of its history. This is in sharp contrast with Mesopothamia civilizations. Maybe an Egyptologist could help on that.

Comment: @James   Ancient Egypt did sometimes try to expand south into modern Sudan, west into modern Libya, and northeast into Syria.  Sometimes Egypt succeeded.  I note that the first dynasty united Egypt by conquest, and that Ancient Egypt, like China,  fell apart into separate states and was reunited by conquest several times over its 3,000  year history.

Comment: @NeMo The [Kellogg-Briand Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kellogg%E2%80%93Briand_Pact) predates that by 17 years.

Comment: Good point - we're still in the 20th century though. I doubt any government even pretended to renounce war before then.

Comment: Wrong. The Roman Empire was build on **justified** wars. That's not the same.

Comment: [Just war theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_war_theory) is very old, with ancient Egyptian, Zhou dynasty and classical examples. That suggests that there was some notion of an unjust war.

Comment: That's slightly different from the idea that war is not a legitimate means to an end - Roman just war theorists would say that you can initiate a war under certain conditions. The Kellogg-Briand treaty says that you can't start a war to get what you want, no matter how just your aims might be